# Eclipse remote debugging not working with instance in Weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run remote debugging with Eclipse to an instance of my app which is in Weblogic. As you can see, it connected succesfully:

[image]

But when I run the logic, it's not stopping in the breakpoints; the app works but ignoring the breakpoints I stablished.

Here's WL's log:

```
    ***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http://hostname:port/console        *
***************************************************
Starting WLS with line:
/opt/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_261/bin/java -server   -Xms256m -Xmx512m  -Dweblogic.N                                                                                        ame=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/opt/oracle/wl/middleware/wlserver/server                                                                                        /lib/weblogic.policy  -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true   -Djava.system.clas                                                                                        s.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:/opt/orac                                                                                        le/wl/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/opt/or                                                                                        acle/wl/middleware/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/opt/oracle/wl/middleware/wls                                                                                        erver/server     -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=7099,se                                                                                        rver=y,suspend=n  weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 7099
```

Any ideas?

PS: I have a suspicion, I have two instances of my app in the deployments but just one active and eclipse doesn't show any option where I can point to a specific deployment beyond the ip and port, so that makes me think, how eclipse would know which deployment of the same codebase to debug? Maybe the problem is revolving there... but is just a hunch.

*integrador-transformador* and *integrador-transformador2* are the same app but different instances. Right now we're just testing with one, as you can see only one is active ("activo" in spanish).

[image]

Comment: I assume that each Java VM instance must use its own port. What do you mean by _"just one active"_? Are there one or two instances of the Java VM running and what ports are they using for debugging?

Comment: I assume you see the "[ RUN ]" logging statement appear?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I made an edit showing the log, which says it's listening in the port we're intending to connect for remote debuggin but I don't know if that's the log you're refering to.

Comment: @howlger I added a log where you can see it is listening in port 7099. That's the one we're connecting for remote debugging. It's connected but the execution is not stopping in the breakpoints i set. Also, I added a screen of the deployments I'm talking about.

Comment: @EdgarHernandez My point is, if you're not understanding why it's not hitting a breakpoint, it's useful to be certain that it's even executing the line of code in question. If you can see an entry in the log that you can guarantee came from the code in question, then you have eliminated that as a question. If you can't see that log entry, then it becomes clearer why it's not hitting your breakpoint.